# TBLFM insert new row with current time

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I want to insert a new row at line 2 in a table (preferably using TBLFM), and I want it to be prefilled with the current date (col 1) and time (col 2).

How do I insert a new row (something like `#+TBLFM: @2..@-1=@#-1`?) ?

Here is my current table:

```
| date             | start |   end | lunch |    total | expected |    + time |
|------------------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+-----------|
| [2016-08-02 Tue] | 08:58 | 17:00 |  0:15 | 07:47:00 | 07:30:00 |  00:17:00 |
| [2016-08-01 Mon] | 08:37 | 16:12 |  0:15 | 07:20:00 | 07:30:00 | -00:10:00 |
|------------------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+-----------|
|                  |       |       |       |          |          |  00:07:00 |
#+TBLFM: @2$5..@-1$5=$3-$2-$4;T::@2$7..@-1$7=$5-$6;T::@>$7=vsum(@2$7..@-1$7);T
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line inserts a new row, but with the content of cell 1 "#ERROR".

```
#+TBLFM: @2$1='(let ((org-table-fix-formulas-confirm 0)) (org-table-insert-row))
```

The part with setting `org-table-fix-formulas-confirm` to 0 is so that it doesn't update all the indices in the formulae.

So using two formulae, the following works:

```
| date             | start |   end |
|------------------+-------+-------|
| [2016-08-01 Mon] | 08:00 | 16:00 |
|------------------+-------+-------|
#+TBLFM: @2$1='(let ((org-table-fix-formulas-confirm 0)) (org-table-insert-row))
#+TBLFM: @2$1='(format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]")::@2$2='(format-time-string "%H:%M")
#+TBLFM: @2$3='(format-time-string "%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** My answer is derived directly from `Pål GD`'s great answer. I only figured out how to prevent the `#ERROR` message.

#### Call the elisp functions inside `let` declaration section and return the date string.

Like this

`(let ((org-table-fix-formulas-confirm 0) (x (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]")) (y (org-table-insert-row))) x)`

Below is complete example for your answer code

```
| date             | start |   end |
|------------------+-------+-------|
| [2020-08-12 Wed] | 09:10 | 09:10 |
| [2016-08-01 Mon] | 08:00 | 16:00 |
|------------------+-------+-------|
#+TBLFM: @3$1='(let ((org-table-fix-formulas-confirm 0) (x (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]")) (y (org-table-insert-row))) x)::@3$2='(format-time-string "%H:%M")::@3$3='(format-time-string "%H:%M")
```

Thank you for asking this question!

---

> **This answer was tested using:**
>
> ---
>
> **emacs version:** GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
> **org-mode version:** Org mode version 9.1.2